# How to give the json data in post api request in django rest framework

Tags: django, api, rest, frameworks

I am new to the Django rest framework, please guide me where I made a mistake,
I want to make the API that takes two arguments

1. cat name (which is char field)
2. cat fields (which is JSON field)

I want to put dynamic JSON fields, like it upon the client that they will add the 4 fields data with key pairs in JSON or any number of fields, I hope so you all guys would understand my query.

Please help me, I will really appreciate your help

Here is my Views.py

```py
    @api_view(['POST'])
    @parser_classes([JSONParser])
    def add_cateogry_with_fields(request, format=None):
        if request.method == "POST":
            insert_Serializers = AddCategoryWithFieldsSerializer(data=request.data)
            if insert_Serializers.is_valid():
                insert_Serializers.save()
                return Response(insert_Serializers.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            else:
                return Response(insert_Serializers.data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and here is the serializer class
serializer.py

```py
    class AddCategoryWithFieldsSerializer(ModelSerializer):
        category_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=34)
        category_fields = serializers.JSONField()
    
        class Meta:
            model = CategoryModel
            fields = ('category_name', 'category_fields')
```

the Model.py class is

```
    class CategoryModel(models.Model):
        category_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        category_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        category_fields = models.JSONField()
        parent_category = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    
        class Meta:
            db_table = 'category'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the JSON data you passed has a trailing comma (`,`).

```
{
    "category_name": "site",
    "category_fields": {
        "abc": "abc",
        "def": "def"
    }, # having comma here when there's nothing next to it will have error when parsed
}
```